# Why there is an error while writing a class in css?

Tags: html, css

Im getting an error as  `[css] ) expected` for the following code. Please help me.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu a:not(.label-flat):not(.badge-flat):not(.disabled > a) {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

It is described here: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation

So a selector combination like (.disabled > a) is not allowed here.